# I have logged out and the login block is missing,how do I login back?

Tags: users

I had created a block that has replaced the default block on the frontpage i.e. the login block and I have logged out of the site so how do I log in back?

I have tried:

1. sitename/user/login
2. sitename/?q=user
3. sitename/?q=admin
4. sitename/subdirectory/?q=user

All it shows is "Page not found" or "Access Denied"
Is there any other way I could log in back to my site?

And I'm using Drupal 8

Comment: Any thing custom that was introduced? For. ex. Custom module/Block? Changes to settings file?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the one time login url with drush command: **drush uli;**